# How do I get atonal melody by ear?

Tags: ear-training, hearing, atonal

It's pretty common to transcribe tonal music by ear, but not atonal music. Also, for me, and a lot of mates, it's much easier to get tonal music by ear than atonal. I'd like to know how can I get atonal melodies by ear. A person said that the way to get the atonal melodies is to use trichords, but I don't know what they are and how to use them.

Comment: IMPORTANT POINT, there's a technical difference between "atonal" and "dissonant." People often use "atonal" simply to mean "dissonant," especially if they have encountered the terms but not learned a lot about the details. But music that contains tritones, minor 2nds, major 7ths, etc. can still be tonal. I suggest starting by practicing transcribing and sight-singing these types of works, so you have a good command of all intervals, not just triadic ones.

Comment: (Also, I guess I should explain in detail. Truly "atonal" music doesn't just mean "it sounds clashy." It means it isn't trying to organize around a tonal center—that is, it's not "in a key." It often uses some other organizing system, like serialism. But Stravinsky, Shostakovich, Bartok, etc. are still (usually) tonal even while using dissonances.)

Comment: @AndyBonner more than "it isn't trying to organize around a tonal center": it's often seeking deliberately to avoid organizing around a tonal center.

Answer (score 6):

If you are able to transcribe tonal music I'm sure you should be able to start transcribing atonal music but it will be much slower process at the beginning. If you're not sure if your transcriptions are correct start from transcribing the pieces for which you can access existing transcriptions, do your own, compare to find mistakes and then analyze what sort of mistakes you tend to make. Typically certain intervals might be more difficult to discern and be confident about. Then you might try one of these apps or software tools for practicing ear training to practice recognition of intervals. Many of these apps can be configured to drill only particular intervals. Practicing singing atonal melodies should be a great help as well.

Answer (score 3):

When we transcribe tonal music, we can relate what we hear to known patterns, major and minor chords perhaps, major or minor scales.   Or maybe we'll recognize other patterns, a Mixolydian or Lydian scale, a whole-tone scale, a diminished chord...   So why not recognize ANY note of the chromatic scale, without having to relate to a subset of that scale?  There's only 12 pitch classes after all!    Listen to C - F♯.  Do you REALLY need to hear that as a modified perfect 4th or perfect 5th?  No, you KNOW those pitches!  Just extend that idea.

When I was at college, we had to transcribe short passages of 'atonal' 4-part harmony.   The pure classicists found this hard.  But those of us with some jazz background too often found that a seemingly random set of 4 notes actually formed a familiar 'jazz chord'!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not lucky enough to have absolute/"perfect" pitch, be prepared to rely a lot more on detecting intervals between adjacent notes to confirm or even do your transcribing work when transcribing atonal melodies. If your previous favoured transcribing method was indeed detecting a (local) key and melody notes' positions/intervals from the tonic, that will have to go out the window.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's important to note that the difference between tonal and atonal music requires a different approach.  Transcribing tonal music is often easier because the notes are connected to a larger sense of harmony and traditional form.  With a little practice, musicians get really good at remembering patterns and melodies that tend to fit with a certain progression.  In atonal music, though, this harmonic and tonal "guide" is absent.  Unless I'm very much mistaken, the only real way to get better at transcribing atonal melodies is to go **one note at a time.**

Start by relentlessly practicing interval training with two-note patterns.  There are likely many ear-training software options that will do this for you.  You may discover that you are good at picking out some intervals, like the tritone or major and minor seconds, but others like sixths you are likely to miss.  Then, practice 3-note patterns (but only when you are rock-solid on two-note patterns).  You will, with good practice and lots of time, get better at it.

I'll also say that you might find it hard to locate good resources to help you.  There are a ton of examples where being able to play tonal music by ear can be helpful.  Think joining in on a saxophone with a pickup band at open mic night, jamming with others and having them play a tune you don't know, picking up a guitar and strumming along with a sing-along around the campfire, etc.  But there aren't lots of times where we are called upon to transcribe atonal music by ear.  In my experience this is largely a written form (unless there are secret "twelve tone row clubs" somewhere).

One resource I have found helpful is a book called *Modus Novus,* which is a systematic approach to improving this skill.  It might help to have a buddy play things for you and take turns transcribing.

> [Book PDF.](https://www.ema.edu.ee/oppematerjalid/solfedzo/MTM001_Modus_Novus.pdf)